# odd and even to line

Tags: php, arrays

i have array:

```
$array = ('aaa', 4, 'fff', 2, 'ddd', 3, 'ddd', 32, '3243', 34, 'sdfs', 3);
```

i woulde like make this:

```
  ['aaa', 4],
  ['fff', 24],
  ['ddd', 3],
  ['ddd', 32],
  ['3243', 34]
  ['sdfs', 3]

foreach($array as $i => $a){
    //????
}
```

how is the method for this with PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
array_chunk($array, 2);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php